# Getting first element of the list in each row in a list-column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, indexing

How can I get rid of the nested lists and only keep the first element of each list in `ColumnB`?

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| first | c(1, 2, 3) |
| second | c(4, 5, 6) |
| third | c(7, 8, 9) |

It should look like this:

| ColumnA | ColumnB |
| --- | --- |
| first | 1 |
| second | 4 |
| third | 7 |

In [python](/questions/tagged/python), I would try it with a lambda function giving me only the first element of the list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `map` to loop over the `list` column and extract the `first` element

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(ColumnB = map_dbl(ColumnB, first))
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
  ColumnA ColumnB
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 first         1
2 second        4
3 third         7
```

---

Or in `base R` use `sapply` to loop over the `list` and extract the first element

```
df1$ColumnB <- sapply(df1$ColumnB, `[`, 1)
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(ColumnA = c("first", "second", "third"), ColumnB = list(
    c(1, 2, 3), c(4, 5, 6), c(7, 8, 9))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply. Could I do it the same way if the list elements were characters and not integers?

Comment: @Propostus you can use `map_chr` instead of `map_dbl` (`_chr`) is to return a vector with the class type.  Or you can also use `unlist(map(ColumnB, first))` if you don't know the type of the column

Answer (score 3):

**In case your ColumnB is a real list, then we could also do:**

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  unnest(ColumnB) %>% 
  group_by(ColumnA) %>% 
  slice(1)
```

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
  <chr>     <dbl>
1 first         1
2 second        4
3 third         7
```

**In case your ColumnB is a string, then we could do:**

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
df %>% 
  mutate(ColumnB = parse_number(ColumnB))
```

```
  ColumnA ColumnB
1   first       1
2  second       4
3   third       7
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's another method using only `dplyr` :

```r
library(dplyr)

df1 %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(ColumnB = ColumnB[1]) %>%
  ungroup()
```

```
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   ColumnA ColumnB
#>   <chr>     <dbl>
#> 1 first         1
#> 2 second        4
#> 3 third         7
```

Comment: Interesting effect of `rowwise()`. Was not aware of this! thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 0):

if a list is inside a column of your pandas dataframe, for instance suppose that you have "df"(dataframe) and the column "x" has a list inside and you want it's "n" th element.
The code is :

```
ss=df["x"].str[n]
```

Now s has n th index of that specified column.